# How do I use BrowserSync 2.0's UI with Gulp?

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I see BrowserSync has a nifty new web-based UI with its 2.0 release.

I've got a local site set up with gulp as a task runner and BrowserSync set up as a gulp task.

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

// Static server
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
});
```

When I visit localhost:3001, the UI is not there. When I run BrowserSync on its own from the cli, I do see the web UI.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Your example works for me. Do you see errors anywhere?

Comment: Yes - I see in the console: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Do you have anything other running while you run the gulp task?

Comment: No other tasks are running

Comment: Last thing to check is that you use latest versions. After that I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Yes I'm on the latest. Thanks for checking in and trying to help